# How to implement motion video highchart on Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am able to make bubble chart using highchart library. But is there any way we can implement motion to it.

Example link is below

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/larsac07/Motion-Highcharts-Plugin/tree/master/demos/map-australia-bubbles-demo/

My problem is motions.js and bubble.js are external files. Here in react we are using render method to render highchart.

Below state options will be having motion object and series like below

```
       motion: {
            enabled: true,
            axisLabel: 'year',
            loop: false,
            series: 0, // The series which holds points to update
            updateInterval: 100,
            magnet: {
                round: 'round', // ceil / floor / round
                step: 0.1
            },
            labels: [20181031, 20181101, 20181102, 20181103, 20181104, 20181105, 20181106, 20181107, 20181108, 20181109, 20181110, 20181111, 20181112, 20181113]
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Things',
            colorByPoint: true,
            id: 'deep',
            marker: {
                fillColor: {
                    radialGradient: { cx: 0.4, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)']
                    ]
                }
            },
            data:  [{ "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 38.42, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 38.17, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 38.75, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 37.92, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 37.08, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 37.75, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 37.83, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 37.5, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 38.08, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 36.92, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 13, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 36, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 13, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }, { "color": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "fillColor": "rgba(67, 67, 72, 0.5)", "x": 13, "y": 0, "z": 6, "name": "California" }] 
        }]

  return (
        <div>
            <Highcharts
                config={this.state.options}
            />
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `highcharts-react-official` wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

By using this wrapper, you can in easy way add additional plugins or modules. Below I created a live example with `Motion-Highcharts-Plugin`.

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/6j359qpr6r